# 2.8 Timeline frame jump hotkey

Tags: timeline

In blender 2.79b you could jump forward 10 frames. Is there an equivalent in 2.8 that anyone is aware of? Not sure how to go about setting up a similar hotkey.

From 2.79b manual...
The Time Cursor can be moved in steps by pressing Left or Right, or in steps of 10 frames by pressing Shift-Up or Shift-Down.

Comment: Also would like to know. Very hard to quickly change poses without hotkey.

Answer (score 6):

You can add the missing hotkeys in the Preferences Panel.

- Open *Edit > Preferences*, then click *Keymap*.
- Click *Add New*.
- Expand the panel and replace `none` with `screen.frame_offset`.
- Set the Delta value (keyframes): 10 or -10
- Click the default hotkey `A` and type your hotkey <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>
- Select the Modifier (<kbd>Shift</kbd>)
  [image]
- Save your preferences (if *Auto Save Preferences* is not selected)

[image]

Thanks to Zino.G, who answered this question on BlenderArtist: 
https://blenderartists.org/t/frame-jumping-in-2-8/1156440

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the screen shots!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to jump 10 frames is to move in step of 10 frames is to start to drag with the right mouse button the current frame in timeline (there is current, start and end frame) and then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - it jumps with step 10 frames but always whole tenth like 10/20/30/40/50...

I didn't found better way and I need it too :(

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to work, but its not that convenient.

Comment: In 3.1 the increment with Ctrl is 24 frames.

Answer (score 0):

Totally different access to solve this - you can change keymap to 27x in preferences section Keymap. Choosed keymap set default is Blender at the top of this section, but you can use also Blender 27x but then you will loose new shortcuts from 2.8 so it depends on your preferences.